# Fixed position on wrapper shadow border

Tags: html, css

The site i'm editing is www.bedriftsdesign.no.

I've got a shadow image element (shadow.png) wrapped arround the body.

```
#wrapper {
background: url('shadow.png') no-repeat;
width: 1282px;
margin: auto;
```

I'd like to make the shadow stay fixed while the content scrolls through it inside so it looks like it scrolls over a bump. I tried to add position: fixed like this

```
#wrapper {
background: url('shadow.png') no-repeat;
width: 1282px;
margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
```

But this only made the whole page stick and let nothing scroll. I just can't understand how I should progress to make this work.

Any help to fix that problem would be really appreciated?

Comment: Since your wrapper contains the entire site, I do not see how the site can be moved in relation to it. That is a problem with your HTML to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the body bg img like so and let the rest of the site scroll:

```
body {    
background: url('shadow.png') no-repeat;    
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I've done this to this site (if is that you want): www.kapantzakis-snails.gr

Comment: Great suggestion thanks. Actually I stacked the shadow upon the other background picture, and made it fixed. Thanks a lot.